# localizing existing database

Tags: mysql, database-design, localization

We have a small mySQL database with about 20 tables (All in english).

Would it be possible to localize this database now that it has already been designed and has multiple thousands of records?

What are our options?

Thanks

Updated - 06-08-13 - I am wondering if this solution would work?

Every table that needs to hold localized data should be split into 2 tables: primary_table and table_locale

Let's take the products table as an example.

The Product Title and Product Description fields (and any other text field that needs to be translated) should be moved into the second table products_locale. This localization table will hold all the translation data for a product with the following schema:

```
Id(PK)    Prod_Id(FK)   Locale_Id(FK)    Prod_Title (VARCHAR)   Prod_Desc (BLOB) 
1              1                   1     My product                     My product is awesome
2              1                   2     Mon produit                    Mon produit est génial
3              1                   3     Mi producto                    Mi producto es impresionante
```

Comment: Depends what you need to localize? Product names that are only in a few tables? All entries like comments, etc.?

Comment: Well, I guess it would be just the products table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in this case I would just add a new column for every language. E.g. product_en, product_de, etc. It's simple, fast and clean.
As long as you don't need to dynamically add and remove langauges.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. Im wondering if my scheme i just added to the post, would work?

Comment: Its not what i was looking for and i did not use your answer, but i know it would work, and since you are the only one who replied with a obvious answer, ill give you the check mark and 1 up! - thanks for responding

Comment: Thanks for the points. Why is this not what you were looking for? Your solution is fine too, better if you need to add new languages dynamically, but a bit slower and more complex if your app really just needs a set amount of translations.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give other options just for fun. =)

You can simply ensure that your MySQL instance is using UTF8 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html). You can also look into the national character set for storing text (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-national.html).

The idea would be to create rows instead of columns and then either introduce a language field - or have an external mapping table that maps language to various products.

There are some obvious disadvantages to this approach, but it's possible.

The other option is to serialize an object (maybe as JSON) for the product description and store various languages. You'd obviously have to increase the size of existing fields to account for growth though.

Comment: MY mySQL is using UTF8 and my admin panel for entering data is already in UTF-8